# Placing numbers in a 2D array by a chess knight move pattern in Java using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, chess

```
public class ChessComplete 
{
    private int size;
    private int[][] board;
    private long callNum;

    public ChessComplete(int size)//constructor with 2D array size as a parameter
    {
        this.size = size;
        board = new int [size][size];
        board[0][0] = 1;
    }
    public boolean isValid(int r, int c)//To check the if the number that is added is in the 2D array is in bound
    {
        if(r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= size || c >= size)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Move through the 2D array by placing the consecutive number for each (row,col) until its full
     * Moves Are only allowed in a chess knight pattern
     */
    public boolean move(int r, int c, int count) {
    callNum++;

    if (!isValid(r, c)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (count == (size * size))// Base case if count reaches the end of 2D
                                // array

    {

        return true;
    }
    board[r][c] = count;// fills the positon with the current count

    if (board[r][c] == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if each possible move is valid or not
    if (board[r][c] != 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            int X[] = { 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2 };
            int Y[] = { 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };

            // Position of knight after move
            int x = r + X[i];
            int y = c + Y[i];

            if (move(x, y, count + 1)) {

                return move(x, y, count + 1);
            }

        }
    }
    board[r][c] = 0;
    return false;
}
    public long getSteps()//Number of reccursive trials
    {
        return callNum;
    }
    public void displayBoard()
    {
        String s = " ";
        for(int r = 0; r < size; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < size; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(board[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1,  0,  0,  0,  0, 

0,  0,  0,  23, 0, 

0,  2,  0,  0,  0, 

0,  0,  0,  0, 24, 

0,  0,  3,  0,  0 

Recursive method call count: 78,293,671
```

#### Explanation

Notice at position (row, coloumn) `(0, 0)` there is a `1` and at position `(2, 1)` there is a `2`. As you can see, the knight in chess board moves in a similar way. In this way We need to populate the whole 2D array with consecutive numbers such that it strictly follows the knight pattern.

#### The problem

I don't get why the whole 2D array is not being filled with all other consecutive numbers. For instance, after filling the position with 3 in the 2D array, the numbers skips all the way to 23.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Can you post your main code and the expected output array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't checking that the square is unoccupied before performing the move, so your solution includes duplicate moves which write over each other.

Change `isValid` to check that the target square is empty:

```
public boolean isValid(int r, int c) {
    if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= size || c >= size || board[r][c] != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

... and remove the initialisation step `board[0][0] = 1;` in the constructor (it should be set by the first call to `move`).

Additionally (but not fatally),

```
if (move(x, y, count + 1)) {
    return move(x, y, count + 1);
}
```

Should be

```
if (move(x, y, count + 1)) {
    return true;
}
```

And the checks `if (board[r][c] == 0)` and `if (board[r][c] != 0)` don't do anything because they occur just after you've set `board[r][c] = count;`.

Comment: Thank You so much, it works perfectly, actually my original code in school just dint have the check board[r][c] != 0 in the isValid() method.